# jQuery - traverse dom - array - extract id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to access the id of the element *nextElementSibling*  in the array presented in the picture below:

```
items[3].item.nextElementSibling.attr('id'))
```

This query does not work. Whereas I can access the id of the item element like so:

```
items[3].item.attr('id'))
```

Can someone explain me why the second works, whereas the first does not work!?
Thanks for your help!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.attr()` is a jQuery function, but you are not testing it on a jQuery object (`$()`). Just get its id directly with normal JavaScipt:

```
items[3].item.nextElementSibling.id
```

Or wrap it in `$()` to access jQuery functions:

```
$(items[3].item.nextElementSibling).attr('id')
```